Создание папки для загрузки
Подскажите, как создать папку для загрузки \файлов на сервер, если я могу подключиться под toor (и поднять права под root) но сам я не поднимал сервер?
Глобальная задача звучит так: я вносил коррективы в действующий сайт, но делал это на тестовом сервере (который сам же поднял). Теперь мне нужно обновить файлы на рабочем сервере. Использую для этого winSCP, но при прямой загрузке выпадает ошибка: недостаточно прав (это и логично). На тестовом сервере было то же самое, но там я загружал в папку пользователя, который был создан при поднятии сервера.
Теперь я хочу сделать также, но мне нужна папка на рабочем сервере.
ОС на обоих серверах ubuntu 16.04

В первых НИКОГДА не поднимай права до рута, а подключайся от юзера, с правами работающего веб сервера. (точнее это вебсервер должен работать с правами ftp/www-юзера). Во вторых не понятно какие проблемы в создании каталога, но тебе это не надо. Тебе нужно просто скопировать файлы к каталог сайта. Скопировать с правильными правами. См п1.

@SeVlad было бы это возможно, не поднимал бы. Сервер поднимал не я, а того "автора" и след простыл...
И копировать файлы не получается: недостаточно прав. Собственно, потому и постарался описать всю ситуацию.

Ну тогда нужно правильно сконфигурировать "тот сервер". winSCP тут не поможет. (разве что узнать под каким юзером там созданы файлы и подключиться с этим юзером.

Решил: создал папку (F7), назначил права toor. всё записалось без проблем. Оттуда уже переместил куда нужно.
